# Using Form Builder -- "How many additional people will you be bringing?"

Tags: formbuilder

Using Form Builder, I want to ask "How many additional people will you be bringing?" and provide the options for 1,2, 3, or 4 additional people. How do I set this up in CiviCRM's Form Builder?

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Could you please edit your question to clarify whether you're using CiviEvent to manage this event? Have you created a "how many additional people" custom field? Have you already started to create a form in FormBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using "Custom Fields". In the menu, click

*Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Custom Fields*

Create a new one with your "Field Input Type" being "Drop-Down (select list)" with your options [1, 2, 3, 4]. Here's a section in the User Guide that explains Custom Fields:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/

Once you add the custom data, you should then be able to add it to Form Builder.